# ARM template for website + continous Webjob

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-rm-template

I am looking for a sample ARM template to create a website and a continous webjob.

(I could only find one for scheduled webjob [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36885075/1942143))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same as that sample, but completely leave out the `Microsoft.Scheduler/jobCollections` part. i.e. you only need to deploy the WebJobs files.

Comment: This is slightly unclear: are you saying that don't need to add anything specific to the ARM template for a continuous WebJob?

Comment: It's no different from deploying a web app. You just need to deploy the relevant files, e.g. via ARM msdeploy provider

Comment: Right, so if you have a properly provisioned web app, you don't need to modify the ARM template in any way. you just deploy the continuous WebJob as part of the web app, and it will work?